# C#. Validation of date pattern

Tags: c#, validation

In my application user can specify the pattern for dates by entering it in the textbox. This pattern is used for logging messages. For example, if user specify 'dd-MM' then in the log file he could see following:

```
[12-06] Some message...
[02-09] Some message 2...
```

How to validate this pattern? How to protect entering wrong patterns?

Comment: So you know it's date.  You want to make sure it conforms to the date pattern?

Comment: If it's in the beginning of a month, how would you be able to tell the difference between `dd-MM` and `MM-dd`. Or maybe there's a lot of messages today so it should be every minute so it's `hh-mm`?

Comment: Considering the comment by ho1, and your problem. I would suggest you to provide a list of options to the user instead of parsing the text entered.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just try and parse the date.

```
DateTime someDate;

// Valid will be false if it could not parse the date
bool valid = DateTime.TryParse(yourFormat, out someDate);
```

Comment: I would add, if you need to validate on the client browser, just use a regular expression.

Comment: DateTime.TryParse() requires a string representation of a date or time as the first argument (not a pattern for one). It doesn't want "dd-MM" as the OP is being provided; it wants "12-06" that the OP is trying to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions will probably be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Regular Expressions](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) or else, at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/validate-a-datetime-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem. I tried:

```
try
{
    DateTime.Now.ToString(tmpFormatSpec);                    
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // the format spec is known to be bad
}
```

The problem is that date format patterns are SO flexible. Even things that don't render date information are allowed (and are not detected by my sample code):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("bla");  // no exception raised
```

See this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188124/438205) for an even better way (I haven't tried it yet).

Also see this discussion about the problem, with comments by J. Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem. I tried:

```
try
{
    DateTime.Now.ToString(tmpFormatSpec);                    
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // the format spec is known to be bad
}
```

The problem is that date format patterns are SO flexible. Even things that don't render date information are allowed (and are not detected by my sample code):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("bla");  // no exception raised
```

See this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188124/438205) for an even better way (I haven't tried it yet).

Also see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031957/date-format-pattern-validation-not-date-validation) about the problem, with comments by J. Skeet.