# DateTime format string for invalid Format string

Tags: c#, datetime, format, type-conversion

I am trying to format Datetime string using

```
date.ToString(format)
```

If user feeds in wrong format, e.g. "YYYY MM DDr" I would like to know whether I can convert datetime using that format, rather than returning

```
2015 04 DDr
```

since

```
DateTime.ToString(format)
```

always returns a valid String.

For example, is there any method that perhaps throw an exception on failed conversion so that I can catch and decide not display my output string instead of displaying something like

```
2015 04 DDr
```

Comment: Use the same form to parse the string as a DateTime.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696060/how-to-validate-datetime-format

Comment: Here is the implementation incase you are interested: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,429

Comment: The info are useful. I do want to validate the format string itself, not the datetime string to be parsed. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that all the letters inserted in your format are either separators or letters that should be converted to a DatePart, you can check if after converting the date you still have non separator chars that were not converted, as follows:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
    {
        public static string ToStringExt(this DateTime p_Date, String format)
        {
            char[] separators = { ' ', '/', '-' };

            String stringDate = p_Date.ToString(format);

            foreach (char dateChar in format)
            {
                if (stringDate.Contains(dateChar) && !separators.Contains(dateChar))
                {
                    throw new FormatException("Format Error");
                }
            }
            return stringDate;
        }
    }
```

**Edited after @Vladimir Mezentsev observation:**

This code assumes that you are converting only to Numbers, if you are doing something that will convert to Day strings like Tuesday, the logic may fail. To address this scenario the code would get a little more complicated but can also be achieved with something like this:

```
public static string ToStringExt(this DateTime p_Date, String format)
{
    foreach (string dateFormatPart in getFormatStrings(format))
    {
        if (p_Date.ToString(dateFormatPart) == dateFormatPart)
        {
            throw new FormatException("Format Error");
        }
    }
    return p_Date.ToString(format);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> getFormatStrings(String format)
{
    char[] separators = { ' ', '/', '-' };
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    char previous = format[0];
    foreach (char c in format)
    {
        if (separators.Contains(c) || c != previous)
        {
            string formatPart = builder.ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(formatPart))
            {
                yield return formatPart;
                builder.Clear();
            }
        }
        if(!separators.Contains(c))
        {
            builder.Append(c);
        }
        previous = c;
    }
    if (builder.Length > 0)
        yield return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just fixed to suit his needs

Comment: your method will throw exception for "yy-dddd-MMMM" format - but I'm pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: You right, I was assuming only numbers in output, ill think about it and change the answer soon

Comment: @Vladimir Mezentsev the problem was that the format outputed strings also(like Tuesday or Monday). The first code i wrote was not taking that in account. I edited the answer to address the issue you just reported, thanks for your feedback

Comment: This may not be complete an answer but I really appreciate your info, efforts and elaboration. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Rodrigo López thanks for the effort, and I've got your point of view, although it is a messy code in which I dived for several minutes. From what i've seen already you tried to convert all parts and if it does not changed -throw! If so, it is still not perfect, cause if you type something like `today is yy-MM-ddr` then your code will pass, cause every part contains some special format symbol, but obviously we would have really crazy output. More precise solution would check that format converts all characters beside separators. Real solution is unique to everyone and `depends on their needs`.

Comment: @Vladimir Mezentsev - I Agree its not perfect, I also though of this case and just didn't address to not mess the code even more. The main idea is to   guide on one way to solve his problem that he will need to adapt for his needs.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx.  Particularly this part...

[image]

If you're wanting to validate the string used to format the DateTime object, then you'll probably have to write your own using the link provided to know what formats are acceptable, and treat any other characters as errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `invalid` format, because you can parse formatted string with exact same format. Even if after parsing you have not loss in any part of date, that could not form the final decision - `valid` or `invalid` format.

You should carefully consider what can be appropriate for user, even give him an opportunity to construct format from some predefined blocks. Maybe show sample conversion with confirmation.

For specific formats you can create some extension method where you can apply your business rules and throw exceptions when you need it.