# Date format PATTERN validation, not date validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, datetime

I have a `TextBox` where the user is able to enter in their preferred date format pattern (e.g. dd/M/yyyy, yy-dd-mm).

How can I validate this `Textbox`?  I could do it on the server-side by setting the `Text` property of this `Textbox` to `cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` and then catching the thrown exception, but I want to do this on the client-side using ASP.NET validators (a `CompareValidator` or `RegularExpressionValidator`).

This is a very difficult problem to search for as all that comes up are date format validation problems.

Comment: Do you really need the user to have full control over this? Could you just offer a list of "known good" patterns?

Comment: @TheSkeet:  Users can select their globalisation settings from cultural "presets" but we have had requests to provide an override facility on indivudal regional settings.

Comment: How many requests, and how much effort would it take to just add the requested patterns rather than trying to validate arbitrary patterns? (I've implemented date/time parsing for arbitrary patterns, and I really wouldn't want to try to validate it using a regex or anything similar.)

Comment: You have a good point.  I thought that there may have been some standard validation techniques out there.  Looking forward to your 3rd book :)

Comment: I have a javascript keydown/keyup function that puts the '/' in for you as you type, if you would like? Format being dd/MM/yyyy.