# Finding if a string contains a date and time

Tags: c#

I am working on a project where I am reading in a file which could come in two different formats, one includes a date and time and the other doesn't.

When I read in the first line I need to check whether the string contains the date and time or not and read the file and based on the check read the file in a certain way.

I'm guessing this would be some kind of regular expression but have no idea where to start and can't find anything relevant.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
I don't think I've been very clear as to what I am asking. When I read the log file line by line the line may come in as:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
```

Sometimes the line may come in as

```
Col1  17-02-2013 02:05:00 Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
```

When I read the line I need to do a check whether there is a date and time string contained within the string.

Comment: Can you share which what you have tried?

Comment: @Boardy: do you know exactly in which datetime locale format these potential dates will be presented as?  dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss always?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer It should be always in the format of dd-mm hh:mm:ss. I don't think the format changes (note that the year isn't included). I forgot to mention that earlier

Comment: @Boardy: what other extra text could you find mixed in that column which would prevent it from being parsed correctly as a datetime using [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: What I was after is I do a check on the entire string to see if it includes a date/time string. If so, I then go through the string and put each column into a variable including variable, otherwise I go through each column not having to worry about a date and time. Otherwise I don't know if there 5 columns (no date) or 6 columns (with date)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the format of the date has been defined, you can use Regex to solve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testDate = "3214312402-17-2013143214214";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}");
            Match mat = rgx.Match(testDate);
            Console.WriteLine(mat.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I improved the Regex examples a bit

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2**: Found out using DateTime.TryParseExact is a much better way that using Regex Expressions

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
{
    //String has Date and Time
}
else
{
    //String has only Date Portion    
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to check for a Date AND Time :)

Comment: @scartag: if xdatetime == DateTime.MinValue, it means the try failed.  Luckily, if `DateTime.TryParse(x)` failed, it returns false so you don't need to worry about this minvalue check.

Comment: If the TryParse fails the DateTime objects stays with the default value (which is DateTime.MinValue).

Comment: @amhed: No need to check against minvalue if `DateTime.TryParse(x)` returns a boolean if it succeeded or not.  That is, if it will always return false if it didn't succeed.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I could have also used if DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out myDate) and save a line of code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the question, I don't think I made it very clear as to what was required. TryParse wouldn't work the string will contain other stuff which is nothing to do with a date and time

Comment: If the text file has a delimiter (a tab or a semicolon) you can split the string using the delimiter and do what I specified. If not you need to use a regex

Answer (score 2):

```
   string s = " Subject: Current account balances for 21st December 2017 and 2nd January 2019 mnmnm ";//here is u r sample string

   s = s.ToLower();
   string newStrstr = Regex.Replace(s, " {2,}", " ");//remove more than whitespace
   string newst = Regex.Replace(newStrstr, @"([\s+][-/./_///://|/$/\s+]|[-/./_///://|/$/\s+][\s+])", "/");// remove unwanted whitespace eg 21 -dec- 2017 to 21-07-2017
   newStrstr = newst.Trim();
   Regex rx = new Regex(@"(st|nd|th|rd)");//21st-01-2017 to 21-01-2017
   string sp = rx.Replace(newStrstr, "");
   rx = new Regex(@"(([0-2][0-9]|[3][0-1]|[0-9])[-/./_///://|/$/\s+]([0][0-9]|[0-9]|[1][0-2]|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|augu|september|october|november|december)[-/./_///:/|/$/\s+][0-9]{2,4})");//a pattern for regex to check date format. For August we check Augu since we replaced the st earlier
   MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(sp);//look for strings that satisfy the above pattern regex

   List<DateTime> dates=new List<DateTime>(); //Create a list to store the detected dates

   foreach(Match m in mc)
   {
        string s2=Regex.Replace(m.ToString(), "augu", "august");
        dates.Add(DateTime.Parse(s2);
   }
```

Comment: This will take date from a string in any condition

Answer (score -2):

Use this method to check if string is date or not:

```
private bool CheckDate(String date)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: I have made a note of your advice. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

> This worked for us:

If the string value is a valid datetime value, then it will not give any exception:

```
try
{
    Convert.ToDateTime(string_value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

If the string value is an invalid datetime value, then it will give exception:

```
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: I don't really understand you, if you had did it on a way which doesn't need my after-fixes, you had got an upvote from me.