# How do I write a syslog message into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, syslog

I have a code and get a syslog message like this:

```
May 11 10:40:48 scrooge disk-health-nurse[26783]: [ID 702911 user.error] m:SY-mon-full-500 c:H : partition health measures for /var did not suffice - still using 96% of partition space
```

Is there a code in which I am able to put this code in a array like this:

```
array [0] = May 11 10:40:48
array [1] = scrooge
array [2] = scrooge disk-health-nurse[26783]:
array [3] = [ID 702911 user.error]
array [4] = m:SY-mon-full-500
array [5] = c:H : partition health measures for /var did not suffice - still using 96% of partition space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write custom parser using your knowledge of business rules by which those messages are created. There is no magic code which will help you, as well as any programmers who are aware of all possible strings you want to parse.
You can't just split this line by a separator.

Comment: sounds logic. But isn't there a kind of code which asks a full string if there is a part in the String which could be a DateTime-Object?

Comment: Yes. You have to use Regex if you know the format of DateTime instance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917203/finding-if-a-string-contains-a-date-and-time, for example.