# regular expression to validate datetime format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate datetime format MM/DD/YYYY. Here is the code I am trying please help.

```
 function ValidateDate(testdate) {
        var Status
        var reg = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;
        if (!reg.test(testdate)) {
            Status = false;
        }
        return Status;
    }
```

Comment: Refer to http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=13795

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: something is wrong with regular expression

Comment: Trying to validate a date with a regular expression is a good way to go quickly insane - getting it structured to accept all the days of each month, but not invalid days of each month causes a combinatorial explosion. Think about it this way ... you want to reject the 32nd of any month, the 31st for several months, including 06/31 of any year, you have to accept 02/28 every year but reject 02/29 most years, though you should accept it if the year is divisible by 4 but not if by 100, though if the year is divisible by 400 then 02/29 is ok.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try your regex with a tool like http://jsregex.com/ (There is many) or better, a unit test.

For a native validation:

```js
function validateDate(testdate) {
    var date_regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ ;
    return date_regex.test(testdate);
}
```

In your case, to validate (MM/DD/YYYY), with a year between 1900 and 2099, I'll write it like that:

```js
function validateDate(testdate) {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    return date_regex.test(testdate);
}
```

Comment: I edited to add a more complex validation.

Comment: @Supreet: This is only weak validation. You still need a thorough validation on the server side.

Comment: @nhahtdh : how can i make a server side check to validate the format?

Comment: @Supreet: If you are using PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: @nhahtdh ; i am working in .net

Comment: @Supreet: Not sure if they are relevant, but here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator and http://stackoverflow.com/a/371996/1400768 Those are many times better than using a regex to validate a date.

Comment: This is a naïve validation just to ensure that the pattern match.
You still have to validate it server side, I totally agree.

Comment: it does not invalidate 02/30/2016 date.

Comment: Your simple regex pattern was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @noirbizarre This does not work for validateDate("02/31/1999"). It returns true. Ca you please correct it also?

Answer (score 14):

The answer marked is perfect but for one scenario, where in the dd and mm are actually single digits. the following regex is perfect in this case:

```js
    function validateDate(testdate) {
        var date_regex = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
        return date_regex.test(testdate);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

based on this

[dd-mm-yy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

I modified the original to this:

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec))(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:(?:0?2|(?:Feb))(\/|-|\.)(?:29)\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

[test the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/vL5mV7/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = new RegExp((0|1)[0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/(19|20)[0-9]{2});
if(!testdate.match(pattern))
   return false;
else return true;
```

Comment: Using `(0[0-9]|1[012])` is better for checking `MM`, in my opinion.

Comment: This will give syntax error. And even if you fix it, the regex is worse than what the OP has.

Comment: @Dream Eater You're right

Comment: This regex allows the date and month to be `00` which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you can look into [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) link and I hope this may be of great help as its was for me.

If you are using the regex given in the above link in Java code then use the following regex

`"^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$"`

As I noticed in your example you are using js function then this use regex

`"^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"`

This will match a date in mm/dd/yyyy format from between 1900-01-01 and 2099-12-31, with a choice of four separators. 
and not to forget the

`return regex.test(testdate);`

Answer (score 0):

---

In this case, to validate Date (DD-MM-YYYY) or (DD/MM/YYYY), with a year between 1900 and 2099,like this with month and Days validation

```
if (!Regex.Match(txtDob.Text, @"^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0,1])([/+-])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([/+-])(19|20)[0-9]{2}$").Success)                  
{
   MessageBox.Show("InValid Date of Birth");
   txtDob.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It's long, but great:

```
new RegExp(/(?=\d)^(?:(?!(?:10\D(?:0?[5-9]|1[0-4])\D(?:1582))|(?:0?9\D(?:0?[3-9]|1[0-3])\D(?:1752)))((?:0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:0?[469]|11)(?!\/31)(?!-31)(?!\.31)|(?:0?2(?=.?(?:(?:29.(?!000[04]|(?:(?:1[^0-6]|[2468][^048]|[3579][^26])00))(?:(?:(?:\d\d)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])(?!\x20BC))|(?:00(?:42|3[0369]|2[147]|1[258]|09)\x20BC))))))|(?:0?2(?=.(?:(?:\d\D)|(?:[01]\d)|(?:2[0-8])))))([-.\/])(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\2(?!0000)((?=(?:00(?:4[0-5]|[0-3]?\d)\x20BC)|(?:\d{4}(?!\x20BC)))\d{4}(?:\x20BC)?)(?:$|(?=\x20\d)\x20))?((?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?::[0-5]\d){0,2}(?:\x20[aApP][mM]))|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/);
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, answers that only contain code and have no textual explanation, get flagged for the review queues. You can avoid this by adding a sentence or two of explanation.

Comment: Did not explant what function it included and make people confuse.