# Angular Input Restriction Directive - Negating Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

EDIT: Please feel free to add additional validations that would be useful for others, using this simple directive.

--

I'm trying to create an Angular Directive that limits the characters input into a text box. I've been successful with a couple common use cases (alphbetical, alphanumeric and numeric) but using popular methods for validating email addresses, dates and currency I can't get the directive to work since I need it negate the regex. At least that's what I think it needs to do.

Any assistance for currency (optional thousand separator and cents), date (mm/dd/yyyy) and email is greatly appreciated. I'm not strong with regular expressions at all.

Here's what I have currently:
http://jsfiddle.net/corydorning/bs05ys69/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="example">
<h1>Validate Directive</h1>

<p>The Validate directive allow us to restrict the characters an input can accept.</p>

<h3><code>alphabetical</code> <span style="color: green">(works)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to alphabetical (A-Z, a-z) characters only.</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="alphabetical" ng-model="validate.alphabetical"/></label>

<h3><code>alphanumeric</code> <span style="color: green">(works)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to alphanumeric (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) characters only.</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="alphanumeric" ng-model="validate.alphanumeric" /></label>

<h3><code>currency</code> <span style="color: red">(doesn't work)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to US currency characters with comma for thousand separator (optional) and cents (optional).</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="currency.us" ng-model="validate.currency" /></label>

<h3><code>date</code> <span style="color: red">(doesn't work)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to the mm/dd/yyyy date format only.</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="date" ng-model="validate.date" /></label>

<h3><code>email</code> <span style="color: red">(doesn't work)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to email format only.</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="email" ng-model="validate.email" /></label>

<h3><code>numeric</code> <span style="color: green">(works)</span></h3>
<p>Restricts input to numeric (0-9) characters only.</p>
<label><input type="text" validate="numeric" ng-model="validate.numeric" /></label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('example', [])
  .directive('validate', function () {
    var validations = {
      // works
      alphabetical: /[^a-zA-Z]*$/,

      // works
      alphanumeric: /[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/,

      // doesn't work - need to negate?
      // taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354044/what-is-the-best-u-s-currency-regex
      currency: /^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$/,

      // doesn't work - need to negate?
      // taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy
      date: /(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}/,

      // doesn't work - need to negate?
      // taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript
      email: /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i,

      // works
      numeric: /[^0-9]*$/
    };

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',

    scope: {
      validate: '@'
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var pattern = validations[scope.validate] || scope.validate
      ;

      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(pattern, '')
        ;

        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }

        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is it intended that you only want to correct input with invalid characters at the end of the input (cf. use of $ in the first regexps)? I would understand this, because when one types in the middle of the string it is inconvenient that the corrector moves the caret to the end. On the other hand, this will not prevent users from inserting invalid characters... Just tell me whether you expect the validation to only reject strings with wrong endings.

Comment: I'd prefer it to have to match the format as a user types it in. if it doesn't match the format, then the key is not able to be entered

Comment: Then how do you expect someone to enter a date? If you start typing from scratch, then when you type the first digit your input will be refused as it is not a valid date...

Comment: The marked answer works very well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure, there is better way, probably regex is also not best tool for that, but here is mine proposition.

This way you can only restrict which characters are allowed for input and to force user to use proper format, but you will need to also validate final input after user will finish typing, but this is another story.

The alphabetic, numeric and alphanumeric are quite simple, for input and validating input, as it is clear what you can type, and what is a proper final input. But with dates, mails, currency, you cannot validate input with regex for full valid input, as user need to type it in first, and in a meanwhile the input need to by invalid in terms of final valid input. So, this is one thing to for example restrict user to type just digits and `/` for a date format, like: `12/12/1988`, but in the end you need to check if he typed proper date or just `12/12/126` for example. This need to be checked when answer is submited by user, or when text field lost focus, etc.

To just validate typed character, you can try with this: 
[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bs05ys69/216/)
First change:

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(pattern, '')
```

to

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(pattern, '$1')
```

then use regular expressions:

- `/^([a-zA-Z]*(?=[^a-zA-Z]))./` - alphabetic
- `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]))./` - alphanumeric
- `/(\.((?=[^\d])|\d{2}(?![^,\d.]))|,((?=[^\d])|\d{3}(?=[^,.$])|(?=\d{1,2}[^\d]))|\$(?=.)|\d{4,}(?=,)).|[^\d,.$]|^\$/`- currency (allow string like: 343243.34, 1,123,345.34, .05 with or without $)
- `^(((0[1-9]|1[012])|(\d{2}\/\d{2}))(?=[^\/])|((\d)|(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{1,3})|(.+\/))(?=[^\d])|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}(?=.)).|^(1[3-9]|[2-9]\d)|((?!^)(3[2-9]|[4-9]\d)\/)|[3-9]\d{3}|2[1-9]\d{2}|(?!^)\/\d\/|^\/|[^\d/]` - date (00-12/00-31/0000-2099)
- `/^(\d*(?=[^\d]))./` - numeric
- `/^([\w.$-]+\@[\w.]+(?=[^\w.])|[\w.$-]+\@(?=[^\w.-])|[\w.@-]+(?=[^\w.$@-])).$|\.(?=[^\w-@]).|[^\w.$@-]|^[^\w]|\.(?=@).|@(?=\.)./i` - email

Generally, it use this pattern:

```
([valid characters or structure] captured in group $1)(?= positive lookahead for not allowed characters) any character
```

in effect it will capture all valid character in group `$1`, and if user type in an invalid character, whole string is replaced with already captured valid characters from group `$1`. It is complemented by part which shall exclude some obvious invalid character(s), like `@@` in a mail, or `34...2` in currency.

With understanding how these regular expression works, despite that it looks quite complex, I think it easy to extend it, by adding additional allowed/not allowed characters.

Regular expression for validating currency, dates and mails are easy to find, so I find it redundant to post them here.

**OffTopic.** Whats more the `currency` part in your demo is not working, it is bacause of: `validate="currency.us"` instead of `validate="currency"`, or at least it works after this modification.

Comment: In the currency example, the `$` is allowed to be placed at the end of the field. How can i remove it so it is not allowed or just allowed at the beginning?

Comment: Using this regex for currency disallows use of the `$` symbol:
`/(\.((?=[^\d])|\d{2}(?![^,\d.]))|,((?=[^\d])|\d{3}(?=[^,.])|(?=\d{1,2}[^\d]))|\$(?=.)|\d{4,}(?=,)).|[^\d,.]|^\$/`

Comment: @CoryDorning sorry, I thought that `$` should be on the end. You can use `/(\.((?=[^\d])|\d{2}(?![^,\d.]))|,((?=[^\d])|\d{3}(?=[^,.$])|(?=\d{1,2}[^\d]))|\d{4,}(?=,)|.(?=\$)).|[^\d,.$]/` for numbers with or without `$` on the beginning or add `^[^$]` for allowing only strings with `$` on the beginning

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is impossible to create regular expressions that will work for matching things like dates or emails with the 
parser you use. This is mainly because you would need non-capturing groups in your 
regular expressions (which is possible), which are not replaced by the
`inputValue.replace(pattern, '')` call you have in your parser function. And this is the
part that is not possible in JavaScript. JavaScript replaces what you put in non-capturing 
groups as well.

So... you'll need to go for a different approach. I would suggest to go for positive 
regular expressions, which will yield a match when the input is valid.
Then you need of course to change the code of your parser. You could for instance
decide to chop off characters from the end of the input text until what remains passes
the regular expression test. This you could code as follows:

```
  modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
    var transformedInput = inputValue;
    while (transformedInput && !pattern.exec(transformedInput)) {
       // validation fails: chop off last character and try again
       transformedInput = transformedInput.slice(0, -1);
    }

    if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
      modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
      modelCtrl.$render();
    }

    return transformedInput;
  });
```

Now life has become a bit easier. Just pay attention that you make your regular 
expressions in such a way that they do not reject partial input. So "01/" should be
considered valid for a date, otherwise the user can never get to type in a date. On 
the other hand, as soon as it becomes clear that adding characters will no longer 
allow for valid input, the regular expression should reject it. So "101" should be 
rejected as a date, as you can never add characters at the end to make it a valid date.

Also, all of these regular expressions should check the whole input, so as a consequence
they need to make use of the `^` and `$` symbols.

Here is what the regular expression for a (partial) date could look like:

```
^([0-9]{0,2}|[0-9]{2}[\/]([0-9]{0,2}|[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{0,4}))$
```

This means: an input of 0 to 2 digits is valid, or exactly 2 digits followed by a slash, followed by either:

1. 0 to 2 digits, or
2. exactly 2 digits followed by a slash, followed by 0 to 4 digits

Admittedly, not as smart as the one you had found, but that one would need a lot of editing to allow for partially entered dates. It is possible, but
it represents a very long expression with a lot of brackets and `|`.

Once you have all the regular expressions set up, you could think to further improve
the parser. One idea would be to not let it chop off characters from the end, but to 
let it test all strings with one character removed somewhere compared to the original,
and see which one passes the test. If there is no way found to remove one character and have 
success, then remove two consecutive characters in any place of the input value,
then three, ... etc, until you find a value that passes the test or arrive at an empty value.

This will work better for cases where the user inserts characters half way their input. 
Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { ValueChangeEvent } from '@goomTool/goom-elements/events/value-change-event.model';

const noOperation = () => {
};

@Directive({
    selector: '[formattedNumber]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: FormattedNumberDirective,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class FormattedNumberDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() public configuration;
    @Output() public valueChange: EventEmitter<ValueChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter();

    public locale: string = process.env.LOCALE;
    private el: HTMLInputElement;
    // Keeps track of the value without formatting
    private innerInputValue: any;
    private specialKeys: string[] =
        ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'Enter', 'Shift', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowLeft', 'Delete'];

    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noOperation;
    private onChangeCallback: (a: any) => void = noOperation;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
                private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
                private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
                private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    public writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerInputValue) {
            if (!!value) {
                this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.getFormattedValue(value));
            }
            this.innerInputValue = value;
        }
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

    // On Focus remove all non-digit ,display actual value
    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
    public onfocus(value) {
        if (!!this.innerInputValue) {
            this.el.value = this.innerInputValue;
        }
    }

    // On Blur set values to pipe format
    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    public onBlur(value) {
        this.innerInputValue = value;
        if (!!value) {
            this.el.value = this.getFormattedValue(value);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Allows special key, Unit Interval, value based on regular expression
     *
     * @param event
     */

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    public onKeyDown(event) {
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys . .
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
                this.updateValue(this.getBackSpaceValue(this.el.value, event));
            }
            if (event.key === 'Delete') {
                this.updateValue(this.getDeleteValue(this.el.value, event));
            }
            return;
        }
        const next: string = this.concatAtIndex(this.el.value, event);
        if (this.configuration.angularPipe && this.configuration.angularPipe.length > 0) {
            if (!this.el.value.includes('.')
                && (this.configuration.min == null || this.configuration.min < 1)) {
                if (next.startsWith('0') || next.startsWith('0.') || next.startsWith('.')) {
                    if (next.length > 1) {
                        this.updateValue(next);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        /* pass your pattern in component regex e.g. 
        * regex = new RegExp(RegexPattern.WHOLE_NUMBER_PATTERN)
        */
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.configuration.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        if (!!this.configuration.minFractionDigits && !!this.configuration.maxFractionDigits) {
            if (!!next.split('\.')[1] && next.split('\.')[1].length > this.configuration.minFractionDigits) {
                return this.validateFractionDigits(next, event);
            }
        }
        this.innerInputValue = next;
        this.updateValue(next);
    }

    private updateValue(newValue) {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
        this.onChangeCallback(newValue);
        if (newValue) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', newValue);
        }
    }

    private validateFractionDigits(next, event) {
        // create real-time pattern to validate min & max fraction digits
        const regex = `^[-]?\\d+([\\.,]\\d{${this.configuration.minFractionDigits},${this.configuration.maxFractionDigits}})?$`;
        if (!String(next).match(regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        this.updateValue(next);
    }

    private concatAtIndex(current: string, event) {
        return current.slice(0, event.currentTarget.selectionStart) + event.key +
            current.slice(event.currentTarget.selectionEnd);
    }

    private getBackSpaceValue(current: string, event) {
        return current.slice(0, event.currentTarget.selectionStart - 1) +
            current.slice(event.currentTarget.selectionEnd);
    }

    private getDeleteValue(current: string, event) {
        return current.slice(0, event.currentTarget.selectionStart) +
            current.slice(event.currentTarget.selectionEnd + 1);
    }

    private transformCurrency(value) {
        return this.currencyPipe.transform(value, this.configuration.currencyCode, this.configuration.display,
            this.configuration.digitsInfo, this.locale);
    }

    private transformDecimal(value) {
        return this.decimalPipe.transform(value, this.configuration.digitsInfo, this.locale);
    }

    private transformPercent(value) {
        return this.decimalPipe.transform(value, this.configuration.digitsInfo, this.locale) + ' %';
    }

    private getFormattedValue(value) {
        switch (this.configuration.angularPipe) {
            case ('decimal'): {
                return this.transformDecimal(value);
            }
            case ('currency'): {
                return this.transformCurrency(value);
            }
            case ('percent'): {
                return this.transformPercent(value);
            }
            default: {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}

----------------------------------

export const RegexPattern = Object.freeze({
    PERCENTAGE_PATTERN: '^([1-9]\\d*(\\.)\\d*|0?(\\.)\\d*[1-9]\\d*|[1-9]\\d*)$',  // e.g. '.12% ' or 12%
    DECIMAL_PATTERN: '^(([-]+)?([1-9]\\d*(\\.|\\,)\\d*|0?(\\.|\\,)\\d*[1-9]\\d*|[1-9]\\d*))$',  // e.g. '123.12'
    CURRENCY_PATTERN: '\\$?[-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?$',  // e.g. '$123.12'
    KEY_PATTERN: '^[a-zA-Z\\-]+-[0-9]+',    // e.g. ABC-1234
    WHOLE_NUMBER_PATTERN: '^([-]?([1-9][0-9]*)|([0]+)$)$'    // e.g 1234

});
```

Comment: Explanatory text about how your code answers the question will make your answer more useful to other users.