# VBA code for checking filename with a specifc format

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking for a vba code that could help me match a filename to a pre-specified format. I want it to color a cell red if it doesnt match the format.
For Eg: my format is `alrt_OBU_PW_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.txt`
If the file I browse using `application.getopenfilename` doesnt match this format, it should give me an error.

Thanks!

Here is what i have done till now-

I have copied the filename into a cell.

```
FileName = Sheets("Control Sheet").cells(2, "F").Value   
 If FileName = Format("alrt_OBU_PW_" & Format("yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format("hhmmss") & ".txt") Then  
   wqI.range("G21").Interior.ColorIndex = 43  
   Else: wqI.range("G21").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
End If
```

Comment: please show us what have you already done?

Comment: I have pasted the filename into a cell.FileName = Sheets("Control Sheet").cells(2, "F").Value
If FileName = Format("alrt_OBU_PW_" & Format("yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format("hhmmss") & ".dat") Then
    wqI.range("G21").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
   Else: wqI.range("G21").Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Comment: Im very new to VBA, so excuse any mistakes

Comment: you're not formatting anything Format("yyyymmdd") needs to be Format(now,"yyyymmdd") for example.  I think you'll need to split the string and check for date formats, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops may assist

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Format function with like below one:

```
Format("alrt_OBU_PW_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Now(), "hhmmss") & ".txt"
```

Use correct/exact date & time instead Now().

Comment: I dont want to hard code the date and time as they will change.