# Can I use replace with unknown string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

suppose i have string

```
'bold':'','Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy','Lowercase':''
```

or

```
'bold':'','Lowercase':'','Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

or

```
'Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

can be in any place within comma seperated string

and i want to replace

```
'Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy' with blank
```

and

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

can be any string (dynamic value)

please tell me how to do that.
Advance thanks for help.

Comment: why do I feel as though this is a JSON file or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Javascript object from the string and make the value of the key `""`

```js
var string = "'bold':'','Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy','Lowercase':''";
var obj = JSON.parse('{' + string.replace(/'/g, '"') + '}');
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{' + string.replace(/'/g, '"') + '}');

if (obj.Dateformat) {
  obj.Dateformat = '';
}

string = JSON.stringify(obj).replace("{", '').replace("}", '');

console.log(string);

//or delete the whole key

if (obj2.Dateformat) {
  delete obj2.Dateformat;
}

string = JSON.stringify(obj2).replace("{", '').replace("}", '');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: @sabithpoker your code is good, but can you please tell me i am trying to use variable with obj like obj.<variable> but it looks for variable name insteadof value.

Comment: just ignore that, your code was helpful for me so i did accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this you wanted??

```js
var str = "'bold':'','Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy','Lowercase':''";

var str_to_replace = "'Dateformat':'mm/dd/yyyy'";
var new_str = str.replace(str_to_replace,'');


console.log(new_str);
```

Comment: actually mm/dd/yyyy is dynamic value and this can be any other string depends on user input. i think i need to use regex there but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: @Rik  what do you mean by any other string? it will be any format of date? isn't it?

Comment: @Alive not necessary, it can be any thing.