# Data Frame- remove special character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, data-cleaning

My DF looks like below:

```
id date
1  '  : 07/01/2020 23:25'
2  ': 07/02/2020'
3  ' 07/03/2020 23:25 1'
4  '07/04/2020'
5  '23:50 07/05/2020'
6  '07 06 2023'
7  '00:00 07 07 2023'
```

I need to remove all special characters and numbers that are between ':' so DF should looks like below

```
id date
1 07/01/2020 
2 07/02/2020 
3 07/03/2020 
4 07/04/2020 
5 07/05/2020
```

I can't use a simple:
`df['date'].str.split(':').str[0]` or `df['date'].str.replace(":",'')` beacuse I will lose correct values. Do you have idea how I could solve this?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regular expression to validate datetime format (MM/DD/YYYY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196451/regular-expression-to-validate-datetime-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: try `df.date.str.extract('(\d+/\d+/\d+)')`, though only limited to your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert to datetime, you don't necessarily have to cleanup the string, you can pass `exact=False` to [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', exact=False)
```

Otherwise, for strings, use the `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` regex and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['clean'] = df['date'].str.extract(r'(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})')
```

Output:

```
   id                  date        out       clean
0   1    : 07/01/2020 23:25 2020-01-07  07/01/2020
1   2          : 07/02/2020 2020-02-07  07/02/2020
2   3    07/03/2020 23:25 1 2020-03-07  07/03/2020
3   4            07/04/2020 2020-04-07  07/04/2020
4   5      23:50 07/05/2020 2020-05-07  07/05/2020
```

###### updated example:

Extract with space or `/` as separator, then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) the spaces by `/`.

```
df['clean'] = (df['date']
               .str.extract(r'(\d{2}[ /]\d{2}[ /]\d{4})',
                            expand=False)
               .str.replace(' ', '/')
              )
```

Output:

```
   id                  date       clean
0   1    : 07/01/2020 23:25  07/01/2020
1   2          : 07/02/2020  07/02/2020
2   3    07/03/2020 23:25 1  07/03/2020
3   4            07/04/2020  07/04/2020
4   5      23:50 07/05/2020  07/05/2020
5   6            07 06 2023  07/06/2023
6   7      00:00 07 07 2023  07/07/2023
```

Comment: I added 2 more rows to my DF because no all dates have '/' to recognize what is the date and what isn't. It is confused

Comment: @Tmiskiewicz it's always difficult to generalize without knowing all possibilities, but given the ones in the current example you can match spaces or `/` and then replace the spaces by `/`.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks!