# How can I determine the last day of the month

Tags: c#

How can I determine the last day of the month, for the tested month, when the user enters a date into textbox that is further from the available last day for that month? Also how do I feed that back to the user.

When the user enters the date, for example, of April 31, 2015, the date should automatically change to April 30, 2015.

I would like to try doing this using c#

Comment: In what format does the user enter the date? Why dont you use a `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: 4 people upvote the comment about the duplicate but nobody votes to close as a duplicate? Apart from that the core issue of this question seems to be to detect if the user entered an invalid datetime but with a valid format.

Answer (score 3):

**3rd EDIT**: The below will get you close to what you're asking for but really just make use of a datepicker control it will help prevent the majority of invalid dates and save you a good amount of development time

**2nd EDIT**: So TryParse is beneficial because if the date is valid, continue and your done. If you have an invalid date, which TryParse will tell you, then you can compare the value that was input for the day value and see how close it is to the end of the month, i.e. take 31 - 30 = 1, 1 number off so they probably meant 30

**EDIT**: To answer your question about finding an invalid date check this out: [Validate a DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/validate-a-datetime-in-c-sharp)

It shows how to detect an invalid date.

To answer your question about how to "guess" which validate date they are closest to I'd say it depends on how you have your date entered. If you do something like have them enter an int value for the day value I'd check to see what the highest day value is for the selected month and then see which one they are closest to (this is just a math operation at this point).

I think this will work

```
DateTime lastday = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month));
```

Comment: But how do you detect if the invalid date the user entered is valid if you subtract one day? The difficulty in the question is to parse an invalid date.

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` doesnt help to solve this question since the date is invalid, but could be parsed if the day would be 30 instead of 31.

Comment: You're getting nearer, but it's still difficult to programmatically detect if the day-part of the invalid datetime could be a date in the future which you can fix. Apart from the fact that he should simply not allow an invalid date or use a `DateTimePicker`, it is an interesting question.

Comment: True but I personally am out of ideas, what are your thoughts on solving this?

Comment: I've started to write a method which works with any possible formats but i stopped as i noticed that it's getting really complex and prone to failure. So in my opinion he should not allow the user to enter an invalid date (or use DateTimePicker). Often it's wrong to "repair" invalid input, all the more because the user might not even notice that he entered something incorrect by silently "fixing" him. Maybe he entered the wrong month, so 31 was correct but not April.

Comment: I agree with using the datepicker, going to add that to the answer

Comment: Not only has everything @TimSchmelter said been true, but there is also a reason Microsoft wrote .NET to throw errors in that case, and therefore the programme should forward the error to the user, and inform them that they made a mistake. Based upon the given `31 April 2015`, I can think of several situations that would cause this: `13 April 2015` reversed, `1 April 2015` additional-keyed, `3 April 2015` additional-keyed, `30 April 2015` numberpad thumb missed, `21 April 2015`, `23 April 2015`, `12 April 2015`. And so on. You should always alert the user, you don't know their intentions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way:

```
//first day of next month
var dt = new DateTime(2015,4,1);
var lastDayOfMonth = dt.AddDays(-1).Day;
```

As far as delivering a message back to the user, it depends on the environment, technology and preferred approach.