# Validate date format after conversion in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have an aspx textbox with AJAX calendar extender control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxFirstReceivedDate" CssClass="selectstyle" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="tbxFirstReceivedDate" BehaviorID="behaviorID" runat="server" Format="ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

The date entered in textbox is in "Tue 08/04/2015 12:00:00 AM" format. I am converting the date to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt format using below code in submit button click event.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tbxFirstReceivedDate.Text, ci);
```

I want to validate the date format after the conversion takes place. If the new date format is not in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt, I want to display an error message.

How can I check the format on code behind?

Comment: I think this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/validate-a-datetime-in-c-sharp.  `DateTime.TryParse` also has an optional argument for specifying the format. Does this help?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to validate the date format after the conversion takes place"? The format for the conversion is the format you are converting from. a 'DateTime' doesn't have a format, so once you have converted there is no format any more, it is just a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.TryParseExact` allows for that, like this:

```
var dateString = tbxFirstReceivedDate.Text;
var date format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime theDateTime;

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDateTime))
{
    // Report error about invalid date format here

}
```