# How to validate date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

In my application I created `DropDownListFor` representing date:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, Model.list)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month, Model.list1)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Day, Model.list2)
```

part of the model is

```
    public SelectList list { get; set; }
    public SelectList list1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList list2 { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
```

and then date will be put together in controller

```
 Address.DateMovedIn= new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

The problem is that when date 30.02.2001 is picked application crashes before it manage to get to `DateMovedIn` (where it would be validated).

How can I bypass this problem?

Comment: in model class, in set; of year, month and day

Comment: You should validate your data before you use them in creating a DateTime object. Maybe this post will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/validate-a-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why are you doing this. Just use a jquery datepicker plugin which will allow only valid dates to be selected

Comment: I assume that you in `DateMovedIn` validate stuff like "can't be a future date" and stuff like that. This is in essence something different from validating "string actually represents a date". It's the difference between input sanitation/validation and enforcing business rules. The former is a job for the viewmodel, the latter for the domain object.

Comment: @TasosK thank you, I'm not happy but I will have to accept first part of you comment as the best solution: "You should validate your data before you use them in creating a DateTime object"

Comment: @StephenMuecke simply I was told to this in this way, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the link by Tasos K., you should use DateTime.TryParse();

I don't know what you want to do exactly, but you could consider using the asp:Calendar control. In this way it's impossible to select an invalid datetime.